# Oracle : update column depending on column from another table

Tags: oracle, sql-update, case

I have two tables :

[image]

Column A is the column on which we will take the join. I need to update like :

```
B = if(D not null) then D
    else C
```

I tried this :

```
update Tab1 x
set B = case when
      (select D from Tab2 t2
      inner join Tab1 t1
      on t1.A = t2.A
      where t1.A = x.A) is not null 
then (select D from Tab2 t2
      inner join Tab1 t1
      on t1.A = t2.A
      where t1.A = x.A)
else x.D END
where x.A > (user_input) and x.A <= (user_input)
```

This gives me output as : 0 rows updated.

Also, as a note, I need to do this in one update statement itself. There are other non-dependent columns from table Tab1 to be updated in this same update.

I know that this looks messy and executing the same select sub-query twice is not at all optimized, but I am not really understanding how to achieve this.

Any help or pointers are appreciated!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think [`MERGE`](https://docs.oracle.com/database/121/SQLRF/statements_9017.htm#SQLRF01606) is the best method to do a multi-table update:

```
merge into tab1 t1
using tab2 t2
on (
    t1.a = t2.a
    and t1.a between 1 and 10  -- change this as needed
)
when matched then
    update set t1.b = coalesce(t2.d, t1.c);
```

Answer (score 1):

Should be like this

```
update Tab1 t1
set t1.B = nvl((select t2.d from Tab2 t2 where t2.a = t1.a), t1.c)
where t1.a = :user_input
```

BTW, the `0 rows updated` has to do with the where condition in your update. It seems it is not matching any of the records in your table Tab1 - as is, your statement `where x.A > (user_input) and x.A <= (user_input)` will always evaluate to `false`

Answer (score 0):

```
merge into tab1 t1
using tab2 t2
on (    t1.a = t2.a)
when matched then
    update set t1.b = case when t2.d is not null then t2.d else  t1.c end
;
```